# Connecting multiple wireless devices to one main device using bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

What I want to do is connect to bluetooth enabled devices to one main device. For example two bluetooth speakers to connect to my iPhone and play music.

Do speaker A needs to connect to Speaker B through bluetooth and then connect to the iPhone? IS this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhones music app can only output to one bluetooth speaker at a time.
Either the software would need to support multiple outputs or the speakers would need to have a feature to pair with each other.

So it is technically possible, but not supported by iOS' music app, nor do I personally know of a speaker that does that.